# One-to-many relationship between same entity in Core Data

Tags: ios, macos, sqlite, core-data, database-design

I have entity called `Item`. It has attribute `title` and I want it to have collection of subitems (type of `Item`).

[image]

One item can have many (sub)items. (sub)item is part of right one item. For example, there is item titled as car. It has subitems titled wheels, engine and cabine. Cabine has subitems seat and steering wheel.

How to model it? Should I set inverse to subitems? If I set no inverse, I'm getting warning. And whether it is inverse or not, it is still many-to-many. No way to set it one-to-many.

How should I think of this problem? I don't have much experience with databases and I think there is also difference between modeling in Core Data and in SQL.

**EDIT: There should be `subitems` instead of `subitem` in the picture**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added relationship **superitem** as inverse to **subitems**. **superitem** is **to-one** type with `nullify` delete rule and **subitems** is **to-many** type with `cascade` delete rule. Seems to be the most perfect solution for my case. As bonus I don't have to write my own `- addSubitem:` method (as it is not generated for Swift) because it is automatically added if I set item's **superitem**.

Answer (score 0):

Object modeling and relational database design are quite different, at least on the surface.  The concepts of encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism have no exact analog in the relational data model.  You are going to have to think about the problem in two different ways in order to do both object modeling and relational database design.

There is a model that is sort of half way between them.  It's called the "Entity Relationship model", and this has been around almost as long as the relational model.  This is useful for thinking about the problem and analyzing the data requirements at a conceptual level.  ER modeling is very parallel to object modeling, except that object modeling models behavior as well as data, and ER modeling only models data.

The problem with learning ER modeling for this purpose is that in the present state of affairs, most of the professionals who use ER diagrams do not use them to depict a conceptual model.  They use them to depict a relational design for a database.  So if you learn ER modeling from them, you'll learn a design methodology, and not an analysis methodology.

Data analysis and database design are really very different activities, and it's useful to keep them separate in your mind, even if a single project requires you to do both of them.  Oddly enough, the same division ultimately comes up in object modeling as well.  Some object models are analysis models, and try to clarify the problem space.  Other object models are design models, and try to clarify the solution space.

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledging what Mitty said. You need wrap your brain around objects (not relational tables). Considering your example I would break it down as follows. The top level object is an item such as a car, truck, airplane, boat, etc. Items can have systems such as engines, transmissions, cabins. Systems can have components such as pistons, spark plugs, seats, steering wheels, tires. If you think of all these things as objects, then perhaps the beginning of a model would look like this:

[image]

An item may have many systems. Systems may have many components. Apple recommends setting the inverse, but you should worry more about the relationships and their cardinality (i.e. one-to-one, one-to-many). You can use a reflexive relationship (to self) as you depicted, but I think that limits your ability to really leverage the power of the object model as all 'things' would be represented as 'item' and you wouldn't have the nice distinction of system and component (IMO)